# elasticsearch command is not working with java 11

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04, java-11

i am unable to start my elasticsearch server when i do`elasticsearch` i got this message

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

i am using `elasticsearch-1.6` and 
`java-version` is

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Os->`Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`
when i have java 1.8 elasticsearch was working fine how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Comment: remove `UseParNewGC` from parameters.

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: Open `elasticsearch` as text file, search for this parameter,  remove it.

Comment: its empty no contents

Comment: Alternatively you can try to use latest version of elasticsearch. There is a chance that it is compatible with java 11.

Comment: It is strange. How do you launch it?

Comment: i can not update ES right now due to some reasons ..also i launch elasticsearch server by typing "elasticsearch" in terminal (when i have java 1.8 ES server got started)

Comment: Then `elasticsearch` script shouldn't be empty. You can find it full path with `which elasticsearch`

Comment: UseParNewGC is not there in the contents of 'elasticsearch'

Comment: Probably in `/config/jvm.options`